# pom.xml file is not configured alright

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am having some problems with pom.xml file. I have tried all the solution found over the internet, but no one helped me. I would really appreciate if you could help me. Below is my pom.xml file and the error log.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>EBook</groupId>
    <artifactId>EBook</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>EBook</name>


<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <start-class>com.programmingfree.springservice.Application</start-class>
  <java.version>1.7</java.version>
 </properties>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

error log:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - For artifact {org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. 
     (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources) 
     org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:null:jar}: The 
     version cannot be empty. at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.validateIdentity(DefaultArtifact.java:148) at 
     org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:123) at 
     org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:157) at 
     org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createDependencyArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:57) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.createDependencyArtifact(MavenMetadataSource.java:328) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.createArtifacts(MavenMetadataSource.java:503) at 
     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultProjectArtifactFactory.createArtifacts(DefaultProjectArtifactFactory.java:50) at 
     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:119) at 
     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:330) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl
     $11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder
     $1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager
     $2.run(BuildManager.java:734) at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager
     $1.run(BuildManager.java:300) at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235) at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
    - For artifact {org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. 
     (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources:default-testResources:process-test-resources) 
     org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:null:jar}: The 
     version cannot be empty. at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.validateIdentity(DefaultArtifact.java:148) at 
     org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:123) at 
     org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:157) at 
     org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createDependencyArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:57) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.createDependencyArtifact(MavenMetadataSource.java:328) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.createArtifacts(MavenMetadataSource.java:503) at 
     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultProjectArtifactFactory.createArtifacts(DefaultProjectArtifactFactory.java:50) at 
     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:119) at 
     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:330) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl
     $11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder
     $1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86) at 
     org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager
     $2.run(BuildManager.java:734) at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager
     $1.run(BuildManager.java:300) at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144) at 
     org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235) at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add parent artifact.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

**OR**

> If you don’t use the starter parent, in your pom.xml you need (inside
>   the  element):

```
  <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
```